# i don't know how to get the text

Tags: html

i want to get the values in the text box and it will show in the table
please help! i really cant figure out how to do it i tried looking at samples but i could not understand how to use it properly and incorporate it with this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value from any input with the `.val()` function.  For example:

```
var product = $('#exampleInputProduct1').val();
```

So just use that when building your table row.  For example:

```
$("#addProduct").click(function(){
    var html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td>' + $('#exampleInputProduct1').val() + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + $('#exampleInputDesc1').val() + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + $('#exampleInputQty1').val() + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + $('#exampleInputPrice1').val() + '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    $('#listProduct tr').last().after(html);
});
```

Comment: thank you i was looking at the .val() function a while ago but i didnt understrand how to use it. you are very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Change the $(document).ready method to

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#addProduct").click(function(){

        prdct1Val = $('#exampleInputProduct1').val();
        Desc1Val = $('#exampleInputDesc1').val();
        Qty1Val = $('#exampleInputQty1').val();
        Price1Val = $('#exampleInputPrice1').val();

        $("#listProduct tr").last().after(''+prdct1Val +''+Desc1Val+''+Qty1Val+''+Price1Val+'');
   /* how do i put the value in the text field in this table? */


    });
});